# join tables and turn row into column, Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm working with an Oracle 11g database. I have to join multiple tables together and one of those tables contains result values for multiple tests where each result is a row. When I combine tables I want to condense these multiple test results into a single row.

Below is a reduced example of what I have. I'm querying data from three tables called requisitions, tests, and results for specific tests.

```
SELECT
  requisitions.acc_id
  ,tests.test_name
  ,results.result_numeric
FROM requisitions

inner join req_panels ON requisitions.acc_id = req_panels.acc_id
inner join results ON req_panels.rp_id = results.rp_id
inner join tests ON results.test_id = tests.test_id

WHERE results.test_id IN (1,2,7,8)
ORDER BY requisitions.acc_id
```

This results in this;

```
Acc_ID | Test_Name | Result_Numeric
------------------------------------
000001 | Test 1    | 24
000001 | Test 2    | 1.5
000002 | Test 1    | 15
000002 | Test 2    | 2.1
```

But what I'd like to get is;

```
Acc_ID | Test 1 | Test 2
--------------------------
000001 |   24   |  1.5
000002 |   15   |  2.1
```

Hopefully this is clear.
Do I have to use pivot or something else? I'm still relatively new to pivots and haven't been able to comprehend how to use them yet.

Thanks.

EDIT: This is what I came up with using pivot. Is my first attempt at using pivot so if I'm doing something wrong or something that could be done more efficiently just let me know.

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT requisitions.acc_id
  ,tests.TEST_ID
  ,results.RESULT_NUMERIC
FROM requisitions

inner join req_panels ON requisitions.acc_id = req_panels.acc_id
inner join results ON req_panels.rp_id = results.rp_id
inner join tests ON results.test_id = tests.test_id

WHERE results.TEST_ID IN (1,2,3)
)
pivot(
      MAX(RESULT_NUMERIC)
      for TEST_ID IN ('1' AS Test 1,'2' AS Test 2,'3' AS Test 3)
)
ORDER BY ACC_ID
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get the final result by using an aggregate function with a CASE expression:

```
SELECT r.acc_id,
  max(case when t.test_name = 'Test 1' then rs.result_numeric end) Test1,
  max(case when t.test_name = 'Test 2' then rs.result_numeric end) Test2
FROM requisitions r
inner join req_panels rp
  ON r.acc_id = rp.acc_id
inner join results rs
  ON rp.rp_id = rs.rp_id
inner join tests t
  ON rs.test_id = t.test_id
WHERE rs.test_id IN (1,2,7,8)
GROUP BY r.acc_id
ORDER BY r.acc_id;
```

Or you could use the PIVOT syntax:

```
select acc_id, Test1, Test2
from
(
  select r.acc_id, t.test_name, rs.result_numeric
  FROM requisitions r
  inner join req_panels rp
    ON r.acc_id = rp.acc_id
  inner join results rs
    ON rp.rp_id = rs.rp_id
  inner join tests t
    ON rs.test_id = t.test_id
  WHERE rs.test_id IN (1,2,7,8)
) d
pivot
(
  max(result_numeric)
  for test_name in ('Test 1' as Test1, 'Test 2' as Test2)
) piv;
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. I actually came up with something close to what you had that finally worked minutes before your answer. Only real difference is I used the test_id instead of test_name in the pivot. I'm still working out some other edge cases though that I might have to adjust for.